# 5 pin DIN KeyBoard. System not booting

Tags: keyboard

I have a BIW1B ver 1.0 mother board with 5 pin DIN key board Port. But now it is not working.
I replaced a new port and soldered it back. Still no response. It does not have any ps/2 port
or usb port. may be some connector on the board, but I could not locate it. But there is a serial port to use serial mouse. Can we use this serial port for both ps/2 KB & MS. Please guide me.

Comment: http://www.elhvb.com/mobokive/archive/Procomp/manuals/biw2b.pdf the manual may be of help here. There's apparently USB headers. This is a *really* old system. Kinda odd that it uses AT connectors rather than PS/2 since they were common way before then.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:

http://www.scribd.com/doc/28906146/MOTHERBOARD-INFO-biw1b

It looks like that there may be USB connectors.

Best of luck

Comment: ThanQ very much for links you provided. In link it is indiacting the ps/2 mouse an USB connector but practically it does not have instead it has a serial mouse connector on the board to give male serial port thru small cable. Is it possible to connect this male serial port to mouse as well as to key board by means of wiring. Please guide me