# Keyboard port is damaged & system not booting

Tags: keyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [5 pin DIN KeyBoard. System not booting](https://superuser.com/questions/493103/5-pin-din-keyboard-system-not-booting)

I have a BIW1B ver 1.0 mother board with 5 pin DIN keyboard Port. But now it is not working. I replaced a new port and soldered it back. Still no response. It has a serial port for mouse. No usb port or connector found. System is not booting asking to press F1. but keyboard port is not responding. Is it possible to convert serial port or COM port to convert into ps/2 keyboard port. Please guide me.

Comment: This board is literally ancient! I'd not even consider giving it to somebody, as currently this is way outdated technology. Even some mid-class mobile phones outperform CPUs that are compatible with this. I'd seriously not bother fixing it. If for some reason, the system must stay as it is, just get a similar Intel BX board from an auction page for cheap, and swap it out. If you are lucky, you can get a board for almost nothing. But I'd seriously advise to leave this old platform, as spare parts are starting to be scarce!

Comment: This is identical to a previous question, you can *edit* older questions . The 'answer' here MIGHT be another question... if its fixed up a bit. SU isn't a forum - you might want to re-read the FAQ to get a better idea of how best to use the site.

Answer (score 0):

I have searched USB connector on BIW1B mother board with the help of manual down loaded from
net and connected ps2/key board. Now key board is working and allowing to enter in BIOS set up but key board is hanging in some case. When I press F1 it is not loading windows but hanging keyboard and system both. Please guide me.